# Prolog : what do the results from calling time/1 actually mean?

Tags: time, prolog, swi-prolog

I am new to Prolog (and fairly new to CS/programming in general), and I'm trying to assess and improve my programs' performance by using the time/1 predicate. However, I'm not sure I understand the output. For instance, the query time("MyProgram") yields the following result in addition to the solution to "MyProgram":

`% 34,865,980 inferences, 4.479 CPU in 4.549 seconds (98% CPU, 7784905 Lips)`

What does this mean? There is somewhat of an explanation [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=time/1) but I'm finding it's not quite enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025923/1153801) answer for some general information about the difficulties of benchmarking in Prolog, or any programming language for that matter. The answer concerns the ECLiPSe language which uses Prolog internally so you'll be familiar with the syntax.

Now, let's look at a simple example:

```
equal_to_one(X) :- X =:= 1.
```

If we trace the execution (which by the way is a great way to better understand how Prolog works), we get:

```
?- trace, foo(1).
   Call: (7) foo(1) ? creep
   Call: (8) 1=:=1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 1=:=1 ? creep
   Exit: (7) foo(1) ? creep
```

Notice the two calls and two exits occurring in the trace. In the first call, foo(1) is matched with defined facts/rules in the Prolog file and successfully finds foo/1, whereafter in the second call, the body is (successfully) executed. Subsequently the two exits simply represent exiting out of the statements that were true (both calls).

When we run our program with time/1, we see:

```
?- time(foo(1)).
   % 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 69691 Lips)
   true.

?- time(foo(2)).
   % 2 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (82% CPU, 77247 Lips)
   false.
```

Both queries need 2 (logical) inferences to complete. These inferences represent the calls described above (i.e. the program 'tries to match' something twice, it doesn't matter whether the number is equal to one or not). It is because of this that inferences are a good indication of the performance of your program, being not based on any hardware-specific properties, but rather on the complexity of your algorithm(s).

Furthermore we see CPU and seconds, which respectively represent cpu-time and overall clock-time spent while executing the program (see referred SO answer for more information).

Finally, we see a different % CPU and LIPS for each execution. You shouldn't worry too much about these numbers as they represent the percentage CPU used and average Logical Inferences Per Second made and for obvious reasons these will always differ for each execution.

PS : a similar SO question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582822/how-to-test-the-performance-of-a-prolog-program)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is as [follows](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/statistics.pl?show=src#time/1). The basic data is sampled via the following calls:

```
  get_time(Wall)
  statistics(cputime, Time)
  statistics(inferences, Inferences)
```

What is then shown is:

> **'%1 inferences, %2 CPU in %3 seconds (%4% CPU, %5 Lips)'**
>   %1: Inferences2-Inferences1
>   %2: Time2-Time1
>   %3: Wall2-Wall1
>   %4: round(100*%2/%3)
>   %5: integer(%1/%2)

In a single threaded application and no other applications, we have still %2 =< %3 if there is a separate GC thread, subsequently %4 will be a precentage below or equal 100. If your application isn't doing I/O, and your percentage is very low, you might have a locking problem somewhere.